# Unit testing factory methods which have a concrete class as a return type

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, factory

So I have a factory class and I'm trying to work out what the unit tests should do. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310/checking-the-results-of-a-factory-in-a-unit-test) I could verify that the interface returned is of a particular concrete type that I would expect.

What should I check for if the factory is returning concrete types (because there is no need - at the moment - for interfaces to be used)? Currently I'm doing something like the following:

```cs
[Test]
public void CreateSomeClassWithDependencies()
{
    // m_factory is instantiated in the SetUp method
    var someClass = m_factory.CreateSomeClassWithDependencies();

    Assert.IsNotNull(someClass);
}
```

The problem with this is that the `Assert.IsNotNull` seems somewhat redundant.

Also, my factory method might be setting up the dependencies of that particular class like so:

```cs
public SomeClass CreateSomeClassWithDependencies()
{
    return new SomeClass(CreateADependency(), CreateAnotherDependency(),
                         CreateAThirdDependency());
}
```

And I want to make sure that my factory method sets up all these dependencies correctly. Is there no other way to do this then to make those dependencies `public/internal` properties which I then check for in the unit test? (I'm not a big fan of modifying the test subjects to suit the testing)

Edit: In response to Robert Harvey's question, I'm using NUnit as my unit testing framework (but I wouldn't have thought that it would make too much of a difference)

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Comment: Some testing frameworks require that your classes be virtual so that the testing framework can inherit them.  Some do not.  Huge difference.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Often, there's nothing wrong with creating public properties that can be used for state-based testing. Yes: It's code you created to enable a test scenario, but does it hurt your API? Is it conceivable that other clients would find the same property useful later on?

There's a fine line between test-specific code and Test-Driven Design. We shouldn't introduce code that has no other potential than to satisfy a testing requirement, but it's quite alright to introduce new code that follow generally accepted design principles. We let the testing *drive* our design - that's why we call it TDD :)

Adding one or more properties to a class to give the user a better possibility of inspecting that class is, in my opinion, often a reasonable thing to do, so I don't think you should dismiss introducing such properties.

Apart from that, I second nader's answer :)

Comment: +1 for "let testing drive our design".  Using properties to expose dependencies helps both configure the dependencies, and make them obvious.  Both are good things.

Comment: @nader: Well put - that was what I was trying to say :)

Comment: +1 So often I need to make something a public property so that I can unit test only to find that I needed it later in the code and other people also needed it.

Comment: +1 had the same question about introducing properties to the API to enable UT.

Comment: Sometimes it's NOT okay to expose class internals just for testing. For example, you don't want to accidentally leak an internal mutable object which the correctness of the class depends on.  Several reasons why this could be bad: (a) violation of the principle of encapslation, and (b) class security (other, even malicious, code could alter the class in unintended and undesirable ways).  How do you test factories when you don't want to leak an abstraction?

Comment: @Jim Hurne: I agree, and I never said anything else. There's a big difference between exposing a read-only property which can be inspected for state, and then exposing a mutable reference. We should only do the latter if it makes sense as a whole (which it often doesn't).

Comment: Depending how widely used your API is, I think that speculatively adding these methods because a client might find them useful is going to lead you into trouble in the long run. Every time you do that, you have to maintain and test that method or go through a deprecation process - just in case a client somewhere is using that method. That seems like a lot of cost for a very little benefit; especially if you do it consistently or often throughout your API. My advice would be to keep your API as small and tight as possible - either the client needs it and so should your test or it doesn't.

Comment: That's the typical Microsoft excuse for making everything `internal sealed`. While I admit that this must be taken into account if you ship to thousands or millions of consumers, I maintain that this argument still doesn't apply to the majority of code being produced. Most code produced world-wide has a very limited or well-known set of consumers, so I don't agree that you can apply the Microsoft argument to most code bases.

Answer (score 26):

If the factory is returning concrete types, and you're guaranteeing that your factory always returns a concrete type, and not null, then no, there isn't *too* much value in the test.  It does allows you to make sure, over time that this expectation isn't violated, and things like exceptions aren't thrown.

This style of test simply makes sure that, as you make changes in the future, your factory behaviour won't change without you knowing.

If your language supports it, for your dependencies, you can use reflection.  This isn't always the easiest to maintain, and couples your tests very tightly to your implementation.  You have to decide if that's acceptable.  This approach tends to be very brittle.

But you really seem to be trying to separate which classes are constructed, from how the constructors are called.  You might just be better off with using a DI framework to get that kind of flexibility.

By `new`-ing up all your types as you need them, you don't give yourself many seams (a seam is a place where you can alter behaviour in your program without editing in that place) to work with.

With the example as you give it though, you could derive a class from the factory.  Then  override / mock `CreateADependency()`, `CreateAnotherDependency()` and `CreateAThirdDependency()`.   Now when you call `CreateSomeClassWithDependencies()`, you are able to *sense* whether or not the correct dependencies were created.

*Note: the definition of "seam" comes from Michael Feather's book, "Working Effectively with Legacy Code".  It contains examples of many techniques to add testability to untested code.  You may find it very useful.*

Comment: I like the answer and that book is a god send if you have to deal with either legacy or close to legacy (.net 1.1) code with no tests.  Also good if you are on a team where unit testing wasn't previously done and you have lots of brownfield code that you want to get unit tested that book is super useful.

Answer (score 4):

What we do is create the dependancies with factories, and we use a dependancy injection framework to substitute mock factories for the real ones when the test is run.  Then we set up the appropriate expectations on those mock factories.

Comment: That's great, but what if the concrete types created by the factory have private properties themselves that need checking?

Answer (score 3):

You can always check stuff with reflection. There is no need to expose something just for unit tests. I find it quite rare that I need to reach in with reflection and it may be a sign of bad design.

Looking at your sample code, yes the Assert not null seems redundant, depending on the way you designed your factory, some will return null objects from the factory as opposed to exceptioning out.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to test that the dependencies are built correctly and passed to the new instance?

If I was not able to use a framework like google guice, I would probably do it something like this (here using JMock and Hamcrest):

```
@Test
public void CreateSomeClassWithDependencies()
{
    dependencyFactory = context.mock(DependencyFactory.class);
    classAFactory = context.mock(ClassAFactory.class);

    myDependency0 = context.mock(MyDependency0.class);
    myDependency1 = context.mock(MyDependency1.class);
    myDependency2 = context.mock(MyDependency2.class);
    myClassA = context.mock(ClassA.class);

    context.checking(new Expectations(){{
       oneOf(dependencyFactory).createDependency0(); will(returnValue(myDependency0));
       oneOf(dependencyFactory).createDependency1(); will(returnValue(myDependency1));
       oneOf(dependencyFactory).createDependency2(); will(returnValue(myDependency2));

       oneOf(classAFactory).createClassA(myDependency0, myDependency1, myDependency2);
       will(returnValue(myClassA));
    }});

    builder = new ClassABuilder(dependencyFactory, classAFactory);

    assertThat(builder.make(), equalTo(myClassA));
}
```

(if you cannot mock ClassA you can assign a non-mock version to myClassA using new)