# How do I unit test a factory?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, factory, cppunit

I unit test my classes by giving all my classes an interface. These interfaces have in turn their own mocks.

But lets say I have the following:

```
class IData
{
  GetData()
}

class IOnScreenDataCalculator
{
  Calculate(IData)
}

class OnScreenData : IOnScreenData
{
  OnScreenData(PTR_T(IData), PTR_T(IOnScreenDataCalculator))

    enter code here

  GetOnScreenData()
}
```

Now lets say that I wish to have a number of factories for different types of data and calculators. How can I unit test these factories where my factories are as follows:

```
OnScreenBlueDataForWideScreenFactory
{
  PTR:T(IOnScreenData) Create()
  {
    PTR_T(Data) data = ptr_t(new BlueData());
    PTR_T(IOnScreenDataCalculator) calculator = ptr_t(new WideScreenDataCalculator());
    PTR_T(IOnScreenData) onScreenData = ptr_t(new WideScreenDataCalculator(data, calculator ));

    return onScreenData;
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help,

Barry.

Comment: where's the c++ code? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure the code snippets are really c++, but the example should be something like this :

```
class ExampleIface
{
  public:
    virtual ~ExampleIface() {}
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

class Example1: public ExampleIface
{
  public:
    virtual ~Example1() {}
    virtual void a()
    {
      // something
    }
};

class ExampleFactory
{
  public :
    typedef ExampleIface * ExamplePtrType; // can be shared_ptr instead

    static ExamplePtrType Create( /*params?*/)
    {
      ExamplePtrType p( new Example1 );
      return p;
    }

  private:
    ExampleFactory();
    ~ExampleFactory();
};
```

and the unit test:

```
void test_Create()
{
  ExampleFactory::ExamplePtrType p = ExampleFactory::Create();
  Example1 *realType = dynamic_cast< Example1* >( p );
  TS_ASSERT( NULL != realType ); // if you use cxxtest
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if Example1 is dependant on something which it receives via its constructor? And lets say I create this thing in the factory to make life easier for those who wish to simply create Example1 without worring about all the routing and magic that lies behind it?

Comment: @user607846 You mean use inversion of control? Then you will have to pass that something to the Create function. That something should also inherit from a pure base class to make things simpler and easier to test.

Comment: But isn't a factory supposed to make life easier for those using it? Should they be concerned with arguments? When I program in TDD I end up with a large number of classes and as a result I need factories to tie them all together. If factories take lots of arguments isn't there a danger that they will receive incorrect arguments due to the user not having a deep understanding of how the factory builds everything up?

Comment: For example, if I have a default calculator class which is used internally by another class. A calculator that is of no interest to those using the returned factory interface. Shouldn't I create this calculator in the factory?

Comment: @user607846 Instead of a calculator, it could be a network access class or db access, or anything. How would you test the factory then? By passing mocks, therefore there are no ways around. If you have a need to pass to many objects to a factory, then you are most likely doing something wrong. If they do not understand what a class is doing - then they need to read the documentation or something. No way around it.

Comment: Another option is to instead of using factories, create objects in a class, whose only purpose is to create and connect all objects.

Comment: How would you unit test your example above if Example1 took an argument in its constuctor? How would you know if it received the intended argument as passed in via Create(Param param)?

Comment: @user607846 If it didn't receive correct argument, you would know by having a non-working program. The compilation should fail, or the run time execution would be wrong. For unit test, I would pass a mock for the argument, and check if the method was called (I am using google mocks)

Comment: How would you unit test -

<code>
class ExampleFactory
{
  public :
    typedef ExampleIface * ExamplePtrType; 

    static ExamplePtrType Create(int param)
    {
      ExamplePtrType p( new Example1(param) );
      return p;
    }

  private:
    ExampleFactory();
    ~ExampleFactory();
};
</code>
How do you know that param is passed to the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

I'd call Create() and verify that I get a properly constructed object with the right constituent types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How do I test that I have the correct constituent types? How do I know if I'm using BlueData instead of DarkBlueData? Or BlueWithWhiteSpotsData?

Comment: @user - Is it possible to determine the right constituent types based on behavior of exposed public methods ? e.g. Create().DoSomething() behaves in a distinct/verifiable way if BlueData is used. If not, then I'd resort to something analogous to type-checks in C# - cast the components to the expected type and Assert that there are no failures.

Comment: I'm working in c++ and this is exactly how I'm currently testing my facotries: Create().DoSomething() but I'm wondering if there is a better way or if this is the standard approach.

Comment: @user - I think the behavior check is preferred. The disassemble-object approach would require accessors to test. I prefer to avoid exposing object internals as far as possible. I can't think of a simpler approach than querying the constructed object. I'm ruling out reflection because the language is C++

Comment: this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061552 appears to be related/identical