# Test lambda expressions called by dependencies

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, junit, java-8

I am trying to test some code inside lambda expression which is a call back from another class.

```
class EmailSender {
    private EmailBuilder emailBuilder;

    public void send() {
        String testEmail = emailBuilder.buildEmail("Test Email", bodyContentAppender());
        //send testEmail
    }

    private Consumer<Email> bodyContentAppender() {
        //how to test this through JUnit?
        return email -> email.appendBody("Body Content");
    }
}

interface EmailBuilder {

    String buildEmail(String templateName, Consumer<Email> contentAppender);
}
```

The lambda expression in the method `getBodyContent` is called from `EmailBuilder` which is a mocked dependency in the JUnit test for `EmailSender`. Since I am mocking the behavior of `EmailBuilder`, the code inside `getBodyContent`is not called from  tests. How to test such piece?

**EDIT:**
Capturing the lambda expression through Argument Captors is not a solution in this case as the behavior of `EmailBuilder` is mocked and the actual methods are not called. Secondly, `email.appendBody` does some transformations on an object which is passed by an external API and not straightforward to create.

Comment: Call `getBodyContent()` directly and test that the body is correctly appended

Comment: Could you provide the code for how you mock "EmailBuilder"?

Comment: @Hulk: I got you, mate :) Sadly this document is an argument of most of the people and I haven't found any different one.

Comment: @Hulk Off-topic discussions alert here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is essentially to verify that a factory method did in fact really return the correct object. There is [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310/checking-the-results-of-a-factory-in-a-unit-test), where the consensus is to not test the result of a factory method beyond  verifying that it does indeed return an object of the correct type. The behavior of that object should be tested in the UnitTests for that type.

In an answer to [this related question on unit testing lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688047/unit-test-code-with-java-8-lambdas) Stuart Marks argues that

> If the code in the lambda is complex enough that it warrants testing, maybe that code ought to be refactored out of the lambda, so that it can be tested using the usual techniques.

Now, the real question is: If this was not a lambda, but a concrete class `MyBodyContentAppender` that implements the functional interface `Consumer<Email>`, how would you unit test that? What kinds of test would you write for this class?

You would probably write tests to verify that, given an `Email`, invoking `accept()` does indeed invoke `appendBody()` with the appropriate parameters, perhaps that invoking it with a `null` argument throws a `NullPointerException` etc. You would possibly *not* verify that `email.appendBody()` works as expected, because that is covered by the tests for `Email`. You may have to mock `Email` for these tests if it is difficult to create.

Well, all of these tests can also be performed for the lambda. Your problem is that the factory and the type of the created object are both private, so from the perspective of your test, the only way to access that object is via the parameter passed to the (mocked) `emailBuilder.buildEmail()`.

If you use Mockito for mocking the `emailBuilder`, you could capture the arguments to this method via `ArgumentCaptor`s (see [15. Capturing arguments for further assertions (Since 1.8.0)](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15)), I'm sure other mocking libraries provide similar functionality.

Comment: Precisely the way suggested by @GhostCat. Giving a thought to taking away things as per your quoted argument. Thanks for your references to other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Most mocking frameworks allow you to **check** arguments that are used when invoking methods on mocked object. Respectively, you can *capture* them.

So:

- acquire the parameter passed
- simply invoke the "code" that it represents, and check if that makes the expected updates to an `Email` object you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to test if you actually supply the body content as an argument, and make sure the method is public. If you intend to keep the method as private, then you should test the public method calling it.

```
public Consumer<Email> getBodyContent(String body) {
    //how to test this through JUnit?
    return email -> email.appendBody(body);
}
```

Then you can test it as

```
@Test
public void testGetBodyContent(){
    .... //send different arguments and assert
    ....
}
```

Comment: public method calling it - not possible. This is called by an API method which takes this as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

So when you want to unit test your code  you must ensure that it's doing one job at a time. You method is named as `getBodyContent` but seems like is supposed to do no more work than appending to email body. Hence, you could pull out this method to be public.

Now you could pass the body and get the content.

```
@Test
public void testGetBodyContent(){

consumer<Email> consumer = EmailSender.getBodyContent();

assertEquals("Email Content", consumer.accept(<mocked Email object>).getBody())
}
```

Comment: I dont think we should pull this method to be public. It is meaningless for any external client.

Comment: Then there is no point in testing it. Because you should test business and not the  code meaningless from business perspective.  Usually we avoid testing private methods because of that reason. And if there is a strong feeling something is worth testing then it shouldn't be private. I think that's why Junit like framework don't allow testing private methods.

Comment: No, business can also be inside private methods. Its only the way the get tested is different. The business in private methods get called by their calls from the concerned public methods.