# Testing object factory

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have implemented a factory like the following:

```
class MessageFactory {
   private static final Map<Integer, MessageBuilder> IdToMessage = new HashMap<Integer, MessageBuilder>() {{
       put(StatusMessage.ID, StatusMessage::new);
       put(ConfigurationMessage.ID, ConfigurationMessage::new);
    }};


    public createMessage(byte[] payload){
       int id = getId(payload);
       return typeToMessage.get(id).create(payload);
    }
}
```

This factory recevives a message's payload (bytes), gets the ID of the message from its header and then uses the corresponding message's constructor whose reference is stored in a HashMap.

I would like to implement a test to ensure all messages are defined in the HashMap.
All messages go in the same java package, would it make sense to write a tests which ensures all java clases inside this java package are in the Hashmap?
Do you see any other way to ensure that once a new message is added it is also added to this hashmap? It is an issue in the code I am developing since this kind of pattern is used in multiple places.

Comment: Try building the map using reflection.

Comment: Tale a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34199097/5698534 its not an answer but a different point of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest refactoring your code so that the compiler does the job for you.

**Option 1: Switch Expressions**

Firstly, get acquainted with [switch expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-switch) introduced in Java 12.

> Exhaustiveness
>
> When using switch statements, **it doesn't really matter if all cases are covered**.
>
> For switch expressions though, the compiler insists that **all possible cases are covered**.

To apply it in your case:

- create new MessageType enum
- allow MessageType to be created from int id
- refactor crateMessage to take advantage of the switch expression

```
enum MessageType {
    STATUS_MESSAGE_TYPE(1),
    CONFIGURATION_MESSAGE_TYPE(5);
    
    private final int id;

    MessageType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static MessageType fromId(int id) {
       // iteration used for lookup, 
       // alternatively a static lookup Map can be used
       for (var mt : MessageType.values()) {
           if (mt.id == id) {
               return mt;
           }
       }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown message type:" + id);
    }
}

class MessageFactory {
    static Message create(byte[] payload) {
        var id = getId(payload);
        var messageType = MessageType.fromId(id);
        return switch (messageType) {
            case STATUS_MESSAGE_TYPE -> new StatusMessage();
            case CONFIGURATION_MESSAGE_TYPE -> new ConfigurationMessage();
        };
    }
}
```

If you ever add new message type, the code will stop compiling.

**Option 2: methods on enum**

```
enum MessageType {
    STATUS_MESSAGE_TYPE(1, StatusMessage::new),
    CONFIGURATION_MESSAGE_TYPE(5, ConfigurationMessage::new);

    private final int id;
    private final Supplier<Message> messageBuilder;

    MessageType(int id, Supplier<Message> messageBuilder) {
        this.id = id;
        this.messageBuilder = messageBuilder;
    }

    Message create() {
        return messageBuilder.get();
    }

    public static MessageType fromId(int id) {
        // iteration used for lookup,
        // alternatively a static lookup Map can be used
        for (var mt : MessageType.values()) {
            if (mt.id == id) {
                return mt;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown message type:" + id);
    }
}

class MessageFactory {
    static Message create(byte[] payload) {
        var id = getId(payload);
        var messageType = MessageType.fromId(id);
        return messageType.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!
Sadly I can't use option 1 since I am limitted to java 8 (not even all of it) since the library must be compatible with android.
However option 2 does seem to do the trick, I will try it out later and see how it ends up looking, thank you!

Comment: Also remember that for additional flexibility, you can define a method as abstract in the enum, and override it in each constant.